# Error when I put DataSets in a folder

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, directory

I create a dataset. Within my program I used the dataset like this:

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
```

And no error at all.

But when I move the DataSet1 to a folder within my solution like I do when organizing the forms I got an error.
Why it gives me error when I put my DataSets in a folder? How I will Organized my DataSets if it is not allowed to make a folder for it?

Comment: -1: I Just can't figure out a way to explain why easily... Unclear?

Comment: -1: This question is not clear: a vague description of a problem is given with no details and no context.

Comment: Can you add code to your question which demonstrates what you're trying and what error or unexpected behavior you're seeing?

Comment: You probably need `using FolderName.SubFolderName` at the top of the class where you're using `DataSet1`, where the folder names are where you've put the class

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I think this question is not very clear but can be understandable, not worth being voted down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Dataset in a folder, the default namespace of the dataset is the folder name. So where you want to use it, you need to use the full foldername as the namespace, like this:

```
FolderName.SubFolderName.DataSet1 ds = new FolderName.SubFolderName.DataSet1();
```

Or at the top of the class where you're trying to use the dataset, add a using:

```
using FolderName.SubFolderName;
```